# Chosen Rails select menu value_method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, jquery-chosen

I'm using simple_form and have a collection select that is long. I have been playing with chosen.js (the rails gem: https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails). I have successfully implemented the gem and it is working, however it is writing the option number to the database, regardless of the fact that I am calling the value_method to force the value of the database to be the content of the selection, not the select box option.

Here is the successful call:

```
<%= f.input :zip_code, collection: Zip.all, label_method: :zip_name, value_method: :zip_name, label: "Zip Code:", input_html: {class: 'chosen-select'}  %>
```

Thanks Stack!

Comment: If you have a relation `belongs_to :zip_code`, it will try to set the attribute `zip_code_id` to the corresponding id of the Zip object select, not it's name.

Comment: I have a relationship setup, but is there a way to set the attribute to the content of the selection, not the id of it?

Comment: I don't know/see/understand why someone would do that? After the relation is created (The object A received the primary key of B and set it as a foreign key), you can just do `my_object.zip_code.zip_name` to display the Zip code's name belonging to `my_object`. The behavior you are implying would be to just do `my_object.zip_code` # => Returns the zip_code's name, but it has to return the related object.

Comment: I don't need to display it though. The database is polled for the field contents to display on another application, that is the point of the value_method set by simple_form.

Comment: simple_form's documentation says: "*value_method => the value method to be applied to the collection to retrieve the value*", not to *set* the value -- Oh I read again your question and I might be totally off-topic, I didn't understand what you want...